# Utilizando tema com laravel

Tags: laravel

Bom, estou precisando utilizar um tema porém não estou entendendo aonde devo colocar os arquivos, além disto estou tendo problemas com a importação dos arquivos css, na verdade os arquivos estou colocando dentro de views. Minhas estruturas de pasta esta da seguinte maneira:

```
-resources
-css
-errors
-fonts
-img
-less
-media
-vendor
-vendors
-index.blade.php (Pagina index onde tem o html base)
-meio.blade.php (Pagina onde tem o conteúdo da pagina principal.)
```

Estou importando os arquivos da seguinte maneira na pagina index.blade.php`

```
 <link href="/../resources/views/vendors/bower_components/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

O erro que esta dando é este no `console.log` do navegador:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Como deve ficar minhas estruturas de pastas para reconhecer o css, e para melhor dividir o projeto ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Arquivos deste tipo somente são acessiveis dentro da pasta public.

Coloque seus arquivos dentro da pasta public, por exemplo:

```
public/css
public/images
public/fonts
public/js
```

Em seguida você pode chama-los dentro de suas views, assim:

```
{{ HTML::script('js/animate.css/animate.min.css'); }}

{{ HTML::style('css/style.css'); }}
```

O ideal é compactar e minimizar estes arquivos em um único, dessa forma diminui a quantidade de requisições que o browser faz para buscar as dependências do seu site aumentando a velocidade de carregamento do mesmo.

O laravel já vem com o laravel-elixir integrado, o que facilita estes tipos de tarefas, recomendo que você veja a [documentação oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#introduction) sobre este assunto.

Answer (score 1):

Estudando um pouco entendi que arquivos de css, img, entre outros, que fazem parte de uma estrutura deverá ficar na parte de public, pois estes serão os dados que serão realmente publicados.

Apos fazer isto conseguir utilizar todo meu layout de forma normal.

Então o ideal é:

> Arquivos com pastas css/js/img deverão ficar na pagina 'public' do projeto.